# How to find next item starting from the index of the previous found item?

Tags: c#

I want to search for a string in a list of strings and get its index

```
List<string> list; 
int index;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(textBox1.Text));
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Now if the user hits the button another time, the index should be the next occurrence of the search item in the list. How can I do this starting from  the previous index `index`?

Comment: What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It always give me the first occurrence.

Comment: There's an overload that takes a starting index https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `List.FindIndex` is _not_ LINQ ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought anything that gets a predicate including lambda functions and is over lists is `linq` !

Comment: @Ahmad: no, that method existed already in .NET 2.0. LINQ was introduced with .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [overload of `FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s(v=vs.110).aspx) with the start-index:

```
int index = -1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (index == list.Count - 1)
        index = -1;
    if (index >= 0)
        index = list.FindIndex(index + 1, x => x.Contains(textBox1.Text));
    else
        index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(textBox1.Text));
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

or shorter:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (index == list.Count - 1)
        index = -1;
    index = list.FindIndex(++index, x => x.Contains(textBox1.Text));
    if (index >= 0)
        listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
}
```